# Delphi SQLite insert into a table with primary key as Autoincrement

Tags: sqlite, delphi-xe, zeos

I am trying to migrate my app from mySQL to SQLite, and in order to do that I recreated all my mySQL tables in SQLite.

I read about the fact that [AUTOINCREMENT](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) is not recommended to be used in declaring the actual autoincrement field. And instead of that I should just declare my autoincrement field as PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, and SQLite would autoincrement it.
All is fine except it does not work or I can't use it.

I use Delphi XE with Zeos and SQLite-3

Here is what I tried:

1.

```
  dm.ZConnection1.Protocol := 'sqlite-3';
  dm.ZConnection1.Database := 'myDB.s3db';
  dm.ZConnection1.Connect;
  dm.ZConnection1.ExecuteDirect('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test ('+
  '  id int AUTOINC PRIMARY KEY,'+
  '  myval varchar(200) default NULL);');

  dm.ZConnection1.ExecuteDirect('insert into test (myval) values (''first'')');
  dm.ZConnection1.ExecuteDirect('insert into test (myval) values (''second'')');
  dm.ZConnection1.ExecuteDirect('insert into test (myval) values (''third'')');
  dm.ZConnection1.ExecuteDirect('insert into test (myval) values (''fourth'')');
```

If I run the above code, my table gets generated, but inserted rows have no values (NULLs I guess) in the ID field

2. and then I tried replacing AUTOINC with AUTOINCREMENT and I get a syntax error while creating the table near AUTOINCREMENT, so I assume ZEOS does not support declaration of AUTOINCREMENT ?!?!
3. And then I tried without AUTOINC, I just declared the ID field as

   id int(11) PRIMARY KEY,

and my code does not give me errors except the values of ID field are all empty (no autincrementation was done)

4. If I add NOT NULL after PRIMARY KEY, then my code gives me errors because I am trying to insert null values in a NOT NULL field

So please let me know what exactly can I do to achieve what I need without having to manually calculate my next id value on each insert. Is it even possible?

Comment: I think you want `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`  Leaving off `AUTOINCREMENT` is generally advised (unless really needed) because it involves keeping the "maximum value ever used" in a table, which (slightly) slows things down.

Comment: Apparently I should have used INTEGER instead of INT when declaring the id field. I'll just run a few more tests and get back here...

Comment: SQLite accepts many variants for how a field is defined (to be as "not incompatible" as possible with other SQL dialects) but a lot of the time they're almost irrelevant because any field can hold values of any type.  One of the few exceptions is that for a `PRIMARY KEY` field to have the auto-generate behaviour you want, it needs to be applied to `INTEGER` and not any of its similar-sounding variants.

Comment: Yep, that was my problem.The keyword was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

[Some other part of the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid) says:

> A PRIMARY KEY column only becomes an integer primary key if the declared type name is exactly "INTEGER". Other integer type names like "INT" or "BIGINT" or "SHORT INTEGER" or "UNSIGNED INTEGER" causes the primary key column to behave as an ordinary table column …